# Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'operation' in stored trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored trigger

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_operation_insert BEFORE INSERT ON operation
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF NEW.client_number not in (SELECT cl.client_number FROM `client` as cl)
        THEN
           SELECT "NOT ALLOWED" INTO @arg;
        END IF;
        
         IF NEW.account_number not in (SELECT cl.account_number FROM `account` as cl)
        THEN
           SELECT "NOT ALLOWED" INTO @arg;
        END IF;
        
         IF NEW.employee_number not in (SELECT cl.employee_number FROM `employee` as cl)
        THEN
           SELECT "NOT ALLOWED" INTO @arg;
        END IF;
        
        
         IF NEW.employee_number in (SELECT cl.employee_number FROM `employee` as cl) AND NEW.account_number in (SELECT cl.account_number FROM `account` as cl) AND NEW.client_number in (SELECT cl.client_number FROM `client` as cl)
        THEN
           INSERT INTO operation(operation_number, client_number, employee_number, account_number)
            VALUES (NEW.operation_number, NEW.client_number, NEW.employee_number, NEW.account_number);
        END IF;
    END;
//
delimiter ;
```

Here is my code, I triend to check if values which i try to insert already exist.

Tell me pls, what is wrong with my code?

INSERT INTO operation(operation_number, client_number, employee_number, account_number) VALUES(0,1,1,1)

ERRROR: Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'operation' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: Post the task itself, not only the way which you decide to use for to solve. X-Y problem...

Answer (score 3):

Since your trigger runs every time you insert into the table `operation`, inserting into that table inside the trigger would run the trigger again, in an infinite recursion.

Note that the trigger is defined as running "before" the insert, not "instead of" it, so the default action is to proceed with the insert as originally specified, and your trigger needs only to define things *other than* that default behaviour:

- You can insert into or update *other* tables in the database.
- As discussed in [the manual page for trigger syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html), you can change *what* is inserted for the current row by updating values in the `NEW` structure.
- There is no native way to skip the insert of one row, but you can abort the entire statement (which might be inserting many rows) by deliberately causing an error, for instance using [a SIGNAL statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html).

Comment: @Akina You're right, I've made it clearer that an error doesn't just skip one insert.